# How to make phpspec evaluate my constructor

Tags: phpspec, construct

```
public function __construct(RequestSchemaInterface $requestSchema)
{
    $this->schema = $requestSchema->getSchema();
}
```

When I run phpspec for Builder then $this->schema is always null. 
In normal call it sets schema.
I got let implemented

```
function let(RequestSchema $requestSchema)
{
    $this->beConstructedWith($requestSchema);
}
```

How can I test methods of that class if they use $this->schema ?

Comment: This is not clear at all, at least to me. How would you retrieve schema from your SUT into test suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `let()` method uses a stub to construct the object under test. While this is recommended, it is not required. You can create a real object of type `RequestSchema` and use it to construct the tested class:

```
function let()
{
    $requestSchema = new RequestSchema();
    $this->beConstructedWith($requestSchema);
}
```

**Update:**

Regarding the title of your question **"How to make phpspec evaluate my constructor"**: the constructor is executed but, because you use a stub for `$requestSchema`, the call `$requestSchema->getSchema()` inside the constructor returns `NULL`.

You can [prepare the stub](http://phpspec.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/prophet-objects.html) to return something else when its method `getSchema()` is called.

Try this:

```
function let(RequestSchema $requestSchema)
{
    // Prepare the stub
    $requestSchema->getSchema()->willReturn('something');

    // Construct the object under test using the prepare stub
    $this->beConstructedWith($requestSchema);

    // Verify the constructor initialized the object properties
    $this->schema->shouldBe('something');
}
```

Comment: Sory I wasnt very specific. Nevertheless thats a good answear thanks!